# use structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure

I want to use structure in matlab but in first iteration it's run correctly and in other iteration give that message .

> 1x2 struct array with fields:

my code is :

```
    for i=1:lenfd
    currow=rees(i,:)
    maxcn=max(currow)
       if maxcn~=0
         maxin=find(currow==maxcn)
         ress(i).x =maxin
       end
    end
```

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That message is not a warning or error. That's just MATLAB printing the output of an operation. And it does that by default, unless you suppress it by appending a semicolon to the command:

```
for ii = 1:lenfd

    currow = rees(ii,:);   % <=== NOTE: semicolons at the end
    maxcn  = max(currow); 

    if maxcn ~= 0
        ress(ii).x = find(currow==maxcn);
    end

end
```

Note that `max()` may have 2 outputs, the second output being the first index into the array where the maximum occurred. If you know beforehand that any maximum will occur only once, you can skip the call to `find()` and use the second output of `max()`.

Comment: thank you . I dont use semicolon because i want to see result each step . max per each iteration return one value but maxcn maybe contain many values. my code sometime give this error " 
Field assignment to a non-structure array object."

Comment: @sara if that's your error message, then why did you ask about another message?